# Rails 3.2 schema dump turns all UUID columns to text and mangles array declarations with postgres_ext gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, uuid, postgres-ext

Using Ruby 2.0.0-p195 with Rails 3.2.13 and v0.3.1 of the [postgres_ext gem](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext).

It seems that I often have trouble with schema dumps (not SQL structure dumps) using Rails wherein the schema dumper converts UUID columns to text columns and arrays to text columns with defaults of `"{}"`. Routine operations such as `rake db:schema:dump` cause destructive diffs like the following:

```
-    t.string   "dbas",         :default => [],                 :array => true
-    t.string   "industries",   :default => [],                 :array => true
+    t.text     "dbas",         :default => "{}"
+    t.text     "industries",   :default => "{}"
-    t.uuid     "uuid"
+    t.text     "uuid"
```

If I examine the structure of the DB manually or just ask Rails what type of column type it thinks a given attribute has, everything looks just fine.

Naturally, this problem wreaks all sorts of havoc. Short of switching to a SQL structure dump, how can I get proper schema dumps?

Comment: The GitHub issue for this question: https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext/issues/83

Answer (score 1):

With Rails 3.2, you'll need to use `rake db:structure:dump` to dump the SQL version of the schema instead of the Ruby version.

Rails 4 handles more types when using `rake db:schema:dump`, which is what you are looking for.

Comment: Postgres_ext provides schema dump support for native PostgreSQL types. The issue here is that another gem seems to be interacting with postgres_ext. See the issue here: https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext/issues/83